# no idea why i get this error : Method Illuminate\View\View::paginate does not exist?

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to paginate this data :

```
if( $id_act!="" && $id_sous!="" && $id_secteur!="" ) // category and sub categroy and secteur selected 
    {
        $res = Entreprise::join('secteurs','secteurs.id','=','entreprises.secteurs_id')
                         ->where('secteurs_id','=',$id_secteur)
                         ->where('idact','=',$id_act)
                         ->where('idSousCat','=',$id_sous)
                         ->get(array('entreprises.RS','entreprises.secteurs_id','entreprises.Descp','secteurs.libelle'));                              
               return view('list_entreprise', ['resultas'=> $res , 'Secteurs'=> $Secteurs , 'Sous_Categories'=> $Sous_Categories ,  'Activities'=> $Activities ])->paginate(4);
               //dd($res);
    } 
    
    if( $id_act!="" && $id_sous!="" && $id_secteur=="") // category and sub categroy selected 
    {
        $res = Entreprise::join('secteurs','secteurs.id','=','entreprises.secteurs_id')
                         ->where('idact','=',$id_act)
                         ->where('idSousCat','=',$id_sous)
                         ->get(array('entreprises.RS','entreprises.secteurs_id','entreprises.Descp','secteurs.libelle'));                              
              return view('list_entreprise', ['resultas'=> $res , 'Secteurs'=> $Secteurs , 'Sous_Categories'=> $Sous_Categories , 'Activities'=> $Activities ])->paginate(4);
               //dd($res);
    }
    
    if( $id_act!="" && $id_sous=="" && $id_secteur=="") // only category selected 
    {
        $res = Entreprise::join('secteurs','secteurs.id','=','entreprises.secteurs_id')
                         ->where('idact','=',$id_act)
                         ->get(array('entreprises.RS','entreprises.secteurs_id','entreprises.Descp','secteurs.libelle'));                              
               return view('list_entreprise', ['resultas'=> $res , 'Secteurs'=> $Secteurs ,  'Activities'=> $Activities ])->paginate(4);
               //dd($res);
    }
```

but i keep getting this error :

Method Illuminate\View\View::paginate does not exist.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... `paginate()` is not view function it is query builder function so remove `paginate()` from `return view()-.paginate()` add in `Model::where->()->paginate(1)` remove `get()` from db builder and replace with `paginate(10)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`paginate()` should be called from the query, not from view(). So you should change `get()` to `select()` and call `paginate(4)` afterwards.

```
$res = Entreprise::join('secteurs','secteurs.id','=','entreprises.secteurs_id')
    ->where('idact','=',$id_act)
    ->select('entreprises.RS', 'entreprises.secteurs_id', 'entreprises.Descp', 'secteurs.libelle')
    ->paginate(4);

return view('list_entreprise', ['resultas'=> $res , 'Secteurs'=> $Secteurs ,  'Activities'=> $Activities ]);
```